# Write the regular expression that describes the set

Tags: regular-language, automaton

**L {w| w contains any number of substrings 00 and 11 with one 1 occurring anywhere in w}**

My guess is that because 1 can be anywhere so Σ*001Σ*1Σ*11Σ* should be the regular expression. Any thoughts or corrections?

Comment: Counterexample to your guess: `"11"` doesn't match, but is in the language.

Answer (score 0):

Break the language definition down into parts:

```
L := { w | 
  w contains any number of substrings 00 and 11
  w contains one "1"
}
```

The first part doesn't actually mean anything. "Any number of substrings 00 and 11" can include no substrings. It's not saying that the string *must* contain at least one of them. This is equivalent to `Σ*`.

The second part says the string must contain `1` somewhere in it: `Σ*1Σ*`